# LAMP Server @ AWS: Am I Doing It Right?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, lamp

I'm following this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) to set up a LAMP Server based on Amazon Linux AMI template.

I'm getting an Error at this step:

```
sudo yum install -y httpd24 php72 mysql57-server php72-mysqlnd
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
No package httpd24 available.
No package php72 available.
No package mysql57-server available.
No package php72-mysqlnd available.
```

Documentation says I must have started a normal Amazon Linux instance instead of an AMI, but it's not the case.

I can install other versions of the same stuff, e.g. httpd instead of httpd24, and a different version of php (although i'm not sure they'll work together), but I can't see a single version of mysql-server available using "sudo yum search mysql".

```
sudo yum search mysql
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
============================================== N/S matched: mysql ==============================================
MySQL-python.x86_64 : An interface to MySQL
apr-util-mysql.x86_64 : APR utility library MySQL DBD driver
dovecot-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL back end for dovecot
freeradius-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL support for freeradius
libdbi-dbd-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL plugin for libdbi
mysql-connector-java.noarch : Official JDBC driver for MySQL
mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64 : ODBC driver for MySQL
pcp-pmda-mysql.x86_64 : Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) metrics for MySQL
perl-DBD-MySQL.x86_64 : A MySQL interface for Perl
php-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
qt-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL driver for Qt's SQL classes
qt-mysql.i686 : MySQL driver for Qt's SQL classes
qt3-MySQL.x86_64 : MySQL drivers for Qt 3's SQL classes
qt3-MySQL.i686 : MySQL drivers for Qt 3's SQL classes
qt5-qtbase-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL driver for Qt5's SQL classes
qt5-qtbase-mysql.i686 : MySQL driver for Qt5's SQL classes
redland-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL storage support for Redland
rsyslog-mysql.x86_64 : MySQL support for rsyslog
mariadb.x86_64 : A community developed branch of MySQL
mariadb-devel.x86_64 : Files for development of MariaDB/MySQL applications
mariadb-libs.x86_64 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
mariadb-libs.i686 : The shared libraries required for MariaDB/MySQL clients
```

Can anyone suggest what my options are ?

Comment: Pay attention to the big red box at the top of that link. Chances are you want the Amazon Linux 2 document, not the v1 one; it's [long-deprecated at this point](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/update-on-amazon-linux-ami-end-of-life/). (Frankly, I steer clear of Amazon Linux entirely.)

Comment: "Documentation says I must have started a normal Amazon Linux instance instead of an AMI". All instances are created from AMIs.